# Apache Camel: How to use "done" files to identify records written into a file is over and it can be moved

Tags: apache-camel

As the title suggests, I want to move a file into a different folder after I am done writing DB records to to it.
I have already looked into several questions related to this: [Apache camel file with doneFileName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048765/apache-camel-file-with-donefilename)

But my problem is a little different since I am using split, stream and parallelProcessing for getting the DB records and writing to a file. I am not able to know when and how to create the done file along with the parallelProcessing. Here is the code snippet:

My route to fetch records and write it to a file:

```
from(<ROUTE_FETCH_RECORDS_AND_WRITE>)
        .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_PATH, constant("<path to temp folder>"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("<filename>.txt"))
        .setBody(constant("<sql to fetch records>&outputType=StreamList))
        .to("jdbc:<endpoint>)
        .split(body(), <aggregation>).streaming().parallelProcessing()
            .<some processors>
            .aggregate(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME), (o, n) -> {
                <file aggregation>
                return o;
            }).completionInterval(<some time interval>)
                .toD("file://<to the temp file>")
            .end()
        .end()
        .to("file:"+<path to temp folder>+"?doneFileName=${file:header."+Exchange.FILE_NAME+"}.done"); //this line is just for trying out done filename
```

In my aggregation strategy for the splitter I have code that basically counts records processed and prepares the response that would be sent back to the caller.
And in my other aggregate outside I have code for aggregating the db rows and post that writing into the file.

And here is the file listener for moving the file:

```
from("file://<path to temp folder>?delete=true&include=<filename>.*.TXT&doneFileName=done")
.to(file://<final filename with path>?fileExist=Append);
```

Doing something like this is giving me this error:

```
     Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot store file: <folder-path>/filename.TXT] org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: <folder-path>/filename.TXT
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:292)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:277)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:79)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:298)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:207)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:154)[209:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)[:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)[:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: Total number of records discovered: 5
```

What am I doing wrong? Any inputs will help.

PS: Newly introduced to Apache Camel

Comment: can you give full exception stacktrace

Comment: Added more logs

Comment: The splitter has built-in aggregator, you dont need the aggregate eip, remove that, see this page with the _splitter only_ example: http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html

Comment: I already have an aggregator in the splitter (didn't post that in the code snippet) which does aggregation. My main issue is that when (and how) do I trigger the creation of the "done" file so that the other file consumer can pick it up. This has to happen after all the records from db have been written into the temp file

Comment: See that link I refer to, you just need aggregation strategy only. The after the splitter (eg end), you can write the done file - then all the splitting work is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the error comes from `.toD("file://<to the temp file>")` trying to write a file, but finds the wrong type of body (String `Total number of records discovered: 5` instead of `InputStream`.

I don't understand why you have one file-destinations inside the splitter and one outside of it.

As @claus-ibsen suggested try to remove this extra `.aggregate(...)` in your route. To split and re-aggregate it is sufficient to reference the aggregation strategy in the splitter. Claus also pointed to an example in the [Camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html)

```
from(<ROUTE_FETCH_RECORDS_AND_WRITE>)
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_PATH, constant("<path to temp folder>"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("<filename>.txt"))
    .setBody(constant("<sql to fetch records>&outputType=StreamList))
    .to("jdbc:<endpoint>)
    .split(body(), <aggregationStrategy>)
        .streaming().parallelProcessing()
        // the processors below get individual parts 
        .<some processors>
    .end()
    // The end statement above ends split-and-aggregate. From here 
    // you get the re-aggregated result of the splitter.
    // So you can simply write it to a file and also write the done-file
    .to(...);
```

However, if you need to control the aggregation sizes, you have to combine splitter and aggregator. That would look somehow like this

```
from(<ROUTE_FETCH_RECORDS_AND_WRITE>)
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_PATH, constant("<path to temp folder>"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("<filename>.txt"))
    .setBody(constant("<sql to fetch records>&outputType=StreamList))
    .to("jdbc:<endpoint>)
    // No aggregationStrategy here so it is a standard splitter
    .split(body())
        .streaming().parallelProcessing()
        // the processors below get individual parts 
        .<some processors>
    .end()
    // The end statement above ends split. From here 
    // you still got individual records from the splitter.
    .to(seda:aggregate);

// new route to do the controlled aggregation
from("seda:aggregate")
    // constant(true) is the correlation predicate => collect all messages in 1 aggregation
    .aggregate(constant(true), new YourAggregationStrategy())
        .completionSize(500)
    // not sure if this 'end' is needed
    .end()
    // write files with 500 aggregated records here
    .to("...");
```

Comment: "I don't understand why you have one file-destinations inside the splitter and one outside of it." actually the line outside is just me playing around with the done file. If I have the done file inside the splitter it keeps creating the done file for each record

Comment: Well, yes. Whatever you do inside the splitter is done for every record. Therefore you have to write **both files outside the splitter**. After the `end` of the splitter block you should have a message body with the re-collected records according to the `aggregationStrategy` you use.

Comment: Probably again a newbie question. If I take out the writing part from the splitter and my db records can go up thousands of rows, would it not be a performance impact? I wish there was a way in camel to just trigger the creation of done file after the .end() call.

Comment: Ah, the size was the reason for this extra aggregator. Well, **if you need to control the aggregation sizes, you have to add an aggregator**. But do **not place it inside the splitter** like you did. I updated my answer with another example that is adapted from the Camel docs page I linked.